# Filter dataframe rows based on 0/1 matrix with string contain

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I have a big dataframe with rows containing an ID within a string column. I want to reduce the rows in the dataframe based on the 0/1 matrix containing IDs as column names. To illustrate, I created a dataframe `df1`:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-05'],
    'ID':['R: ID1', 'ID2_P', 'L_ID2', 'ID1.I', 'RZ:ID3', 'ID1', 'P ID2', 'ID3 4K', 'ID1', 'U_ID1', 'ID2:PD', 'ID3=2D'], 
    'Ratings':[9.0, 8.0, 5.0, 3.0, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 10, 3, 6]})
```

and a matrix `m1` containing 0 and 1:

```
m1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05'],
    'ID1':[0,0,1,1,1], 
    'ID2':[1,1,1,1,0],
    'ID3':[0,0,0,0,1]})
```

Conditioned on `m1`, the dataframe `df1` needs to be reduced to `df2`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-05'],
    'ID':['ID2_P', 'L_ID2', 'ID1.I', 'P ID2', 'ID1', 'U_ID1', 'ID3=2D'], 
    'Ratings':[8.0, 5.0, 3, 6, 4, 10, 6]})
```

So far, I tried to iterate through the rows of `df1` with a `for loop` but I wasn't able to get a result.

Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with filter `1` rows first:

```
df2 = m1.melt('Date', var_name='ID1').query('value == 1')
print (df2)
          Date  ID1  value
2   2021-01-03  ID1      1
3   2021-01-04  ID1      1
4   2021-01-05  ID1      1
5   2021-01-01  ID2      1
6   2021-01-02  ID2      1
7   2021-01-03  ID2      1
8   2021-01-04  ID2      1
14  2021-01-05  ID3      1
```

Then get `ID` by `df2["ID1"].unique()` in [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df1['ID1'] = df1['ID'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(df2["ID1"].unique())})', expand=False)
```

And last filter by `Date` and `ID1` in inner default join by [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), remove helper `ID1` column:

```
df = df1.merge(df2[['Date','ID1']]).drop('ID1', axis=1)
print (df)
         Date      ID  Ratings
0  2021-01-01   ID2_P      8.0
1  2021-01-01   L_ID2      5.0
2  2021-01-03     ID1      3.0
3  2021-01-03   P ID2      6.0
4  2021-01-05     ID1      4.0
5  2021-01-05   U_ID1     10.0
6  2021-01-05  ID3=2D      6.0
```